# Acess types by index

Tags: typescript

I have an array like this:

```
let arr = [
   {
     test: "testOne",
     values: [{ value: 1, text: "ho" }]
   },
   {
     test: "testTwo",
     values: [{ value: 2, text: "hey" }]
   }
]
```

I want to define the array type something like this:

```
type TypeA = { test: "testOne", values: [...] } 
type TypeB = { test: "testTwo" values: [...] }
```

What i basically want is to pass in types where i can acess it somehow with the index hardcoded.

```
let arr: ArrayTypes<TypeA, TypeB> = [...]
```

Something like this where i say the first object has the type "TypeA" the second object has the "TypeB" and so on, is this somehow possible? I actually dont want an logical OR operator for example test could be "testOne" | "testTwo"

Comment: you can just use [TypeA, TypeB]. Take a look at typescript tuples

Answer (score 0):

You can use fixed-length array types also known as [Tuple Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/tuples) for that.

> A tuple type is another sort of Array type that knows exactly how many elements it contains, and exactly which types it contains at specific positions.

<sub>https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types</sub>

For example:

```
type Tuple = [string, MyType, {another: {comlicated: {type: boolean}}}];
```

---

```
let arr = [
   {
     test: "testOne",
     values: [{ value: 1, text: "ho" }]
   },
   {
     test: "testTwo",
     values: [{ value: 2, text: "hey" }]
   }
] as const;

type Types = [typeof arr[0], typeof arr[1]];

type TypeA = Types[0]
type TypeB = Types[1]
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAhgTjEF4IG0BQEMG90Y2EAzmAFwQBE%20RA8gHYhkA0OuAblMAK6GnKYRucQpAIwMI%20AB4lyACwD2ZCAF8AusyVNc2XHkLSKegCoB3BZp0CuBHn0tCIAJjGT9MkAE9Fq9ahXQCEADGcjREANyoqGDuAA4gEIaxhIgo0XFyAGbQcMgADCrOSZnZMMjCKioRUUkJSQCCKYlxBHlqafFNIABCjUkt5ahAA)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use mapped type in typescript and here is how you can handle achieve it.

```
type TypeA = { test: "testOne", values: any[] };
type TypeB = { test: "testTwo", values: any[] };

type ArrayTypes = {
  testOne: TypeA;
  testTwo: TypeB;
};

let arr: Array<ArrayTypes[keyof ArrayTypes]> = [
  {
    test: "testOne",
    values: [{ value: 1, text: "ho" }],
  },
  {
    test: "testTwo",
    values: [{ value: 2, text: "hey" }],
  },
];


const element1: TypeA = arr[0]; // gives you first element with TypeA
const element2: TypeB = arr[1]; // & the second element with TypeB
```